# having cors error while deploying Flask and React app on a linux machine with nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask, cors

I have developed this app with Flask as backend and React js as frontend.
my folder structure:

```
mydomain/
    /server
        __init__.py
        ...
    /client (react)
        /dist
            index.html
            /assets (contains js and css)
    /venv
```

my nginx configuration:

```
 server {
        server_name <mydomain> www.<mydomain>;
        root /home/sabbir/<mydomain>/client/dist/;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    location /api {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<mydomain>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<mydomain>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = www.<mydomain>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
```

it gives this error when I try to register a user:
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/auth/login. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null)

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing flask-cors: `pip install flask-cors` and then applying it on your app like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```